# Django inspectdb lost comment

Tags: django

I use mysql to test model.

With `django_comment_migrate` helps,  help_text saved to sql table field comment.

Original model.py below:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='alias_name', help_text='alias_name')
```

Run `python manage.py inspectdb` got result below, lost help_text.

```
class App1Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'app1_foo'
```